# REST : Different presentations of same data

Tags: xml, json, rest, jersey, protocol-buffers

I have set of REST web services all of which accept XML or JSON data and also produce XML or JSON data.

Now I have to add support for `Protobuf` format but as protobuf creates its own set of classes, I cannot re-use same classes used for XML/JSON data. As a result of which, I have to copy-paste same web service methods, change logic to accept protobuf type data and return protobuf type response. If I use this approach, then business logic will get repeated at two places and two copies of same logic need to be maintained; which is not really good design.

I've seen this question on SO. This question talks about URL structure, but I am not concerned with URL structure and accept-headers. That part is already in place. I just need to add `Protobuf` format with minimal changes.

So I would like to know how to add support for `Protobuf` in existing REST web services? Has anyone encountered similar problem?

EDIT :

Sorry, forgot to mention that I am using Java, Jersey, Spring.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: @EricStein,  thanks. I have added technology stack/framework which I am using.

Comment: It's not very clear if you want to know the REST way to specify this, or just the way to implement it with a given framework. The REST way is to use "content negotiation" (i.e. using the [`Accept` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1)).

Comment: I'm assuming you want to use a custom `Content-Type` for this, correct? If so, you should be able to implement custom `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` for your media type. It won't be simple but should be do-able. I'd look at the code in `jackson-jaxrs-base` and `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` for examples on how `Jackson` implements json handling.